# Calling React useState and passing it a value... Which returns to me that, SetCurrentId is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Below is the code where am mapping through an array then I setCuurentId(item._id) in the first Button icon and also passing history.push(`/update/${item._id}`)
But the issue here is when ever I click the onClick Button it return that setCurrentId is not a function

```
{
              // mapping through stock data to display in a table....
              stocks.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                  <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{index + 1}</td>
                    <td>{item.product_name}</td>
                    <td>{item.product_category}</td>
                    <td>{"₦ " + item.product_price}</td>
                    <td>
                      {item.product_qty < 10 ? (
                        <div style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                          {item.product_qty}
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div>{item.product_qty}</div>
                      )}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <Button
                        variant="outline"
                        size="small"
                        onClick={() => {
                          history.push(`/update/${item._id}`);
                          setCurrentId(item._id);
                        }}
                      >
                        <EditIcon hover="white" />
                      </Button>
                      <Button variant="outline" size="small">
                        <DeleteIcon
                          color="error"
                          fontSize="small"
                          onClick={() => dispatch(deleteStock(item._id))}
                        />
                      </Button>{" "}
                      &nbsp;
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                );
              })
            }
```

Below is the error I got from the console page.....

```
 TypeError: setCurrentId is not a function

        onClick={() => {
          history.push(`/update/${item._id}`);
        setCurrentId(item._id);
```

and I defined the useState in the app component...

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(null);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { history } = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    //getting stock data when app initiate, and using redux to save stockData
    dispatch(getStocks());
  }, [currentId, dispatch]);
```

Then I passed the currentId and the setCurrentId to the component childs that need them... below

```
          <Route
        path="/"
        exact
        component={ProductView}
        setCurrentId={setCurrentId}
      />
      <Route path="/addstock" component={StockProduct} />
      <Route
        path="/update/:id"
        component={UpDateStockComponent}
        setCurrentId={setCurrentId}
        currentId={currentId}
      />

enter code here
```

Comment: where is the setCurrentId function defined? you can share a sample of the code on code sandbox.

Comment: The [currentId setCurrentId] is defined in tha app componenet and then I am passing it to the component that needs it as a props

Comment: you need to call the function as props.setCurrentId as setCurrentId is being passed down as a prop to the component.

Comment: I am using destructuring method. Did I still need to call props.setCurrentId ?
 and I still used the props method, removing the object destructuring but still thesame issue. props.setCurentId is not a functiomn

Comment: share a sample of the existing code.

Comment: Is the `Route` you are using here from `react-router`?

Comment: If you are using the `Router` from `react-router` I believe the implementation you have here is not supported. Here is the documentation for `Route`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#routes-and-route. It does not take arbitrary props such as `setCurrentId`. It only takes the 5 props listed in the documentation there. I see you are doing the same thing for `ProductView`. Does `setCurrentId` work there?

Comment: I am using router but not react-router v6. I am using the old version: my version is  react-router: 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the the `Route` component you're using, I'm assuming that you're using `react-router` in some version before `v6`. If that's the case, the `Route` component will not forward the extra props for the component you're giving to the prop `component`. So the prop `setCurrentId` is not really getting into your component, thus being `undefined` there. You can check the documentation for the `Route` component here:
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route

Although, you can use your components with props if you pass it using either the `render` prop or passing it as `children`. Either of these options should work for you:

```js
<Route
    path="/update/:id"
    render={() => (
        <UpDateStockComponent
            setCurrentId={setCurrentId}
            currentId={currentId}
        />
    )}
/>
```

or

```js
<Route path="/update/:id">
    <UpDateStockComponent setCurrentId={setCurrentId} currentId={currentId} />
</Route>
```